How can I resolve "java: cannot find symbol" error on an Entity Query Service on a JHipster Generated App?
I generated a JHipster app using Java for backend and whenever I try to run the app I get this error:
    root\service\TaskQueryService.java:78:93
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Task_
  location: class ro.package.service.TaskQueryService

This is my TaskQueryService:

I found some people having the same issue but I still can't resolve it. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

IDK if it's a real fix, but with 8.X.X i only manage to create the filters/queries with Gradle not Maven

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
